# New desktop dies when starting OpenGL screensavers

Tags: kde, intel-graphics, intel, opengl, screensaver

I got some new screensavers (`sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-data-extra`) and it had some nice OpenGL screensavers on it. When I start some of them (one of them is a 3d grid of dots and the camera moves around) and then my computer dies and says "The system is running in low-graphics mode" and to get out of it, I have to power down the computer.

I am using an intel 4790K quad core CPU with an ASRock Z97 extreme6/ac mpotherboard and running Ubuntu 14.0.4.2 (though I installed the kubuntu-desktop overtop of it and was running the kde desktop when this happened).

Any ideas on how to fix this?